# Continue creating new elements until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a battling system and I would like to set it up so that instead of filling in #dam's text it will create a new p element until the monsters hp is 0. I want it to create all p elements on one click of the button. Every p element should show up underneath the one above it.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rcmvyc3/)

```
$('#battleButton').click(function() {  
    //playerDam();
  monsterEl = $('#monsterList option:selected');  
  monster = monsterEl.data('monster')
  if(monster.hp > 0) {
    $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsterList').val() + " for " + monster.playerDam() + " damage");
    monster.hp -= monster.playerDam();
  }
  else {
    $('#dam').html("You have defeated the " + $('#monsterList').val() + ", you have received " + monster.exp + " experience and " + monster.gold + " gold!");
    monster.hp = monster.hp;
  }
});
```

Also the way the code is now once monster.hp reaches 0 or less I can't figure out how to reset the hp so that clicking battle works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a textbook situation for a `while` loop. To queue your elements, use `append` instead of `html` then empty your div at the beginning of a fight :

```
$('#dam').empty();
while(monster.hp > 0) {
    $('#dam').append("<p>You have hit the " + $('#monsterList').val() + " for " + monster.playerDam() + " damage</p>");
    monster.hp -= monster.playerDam();
}
$('#dam').append("<p>You have defeated the " + $('#monsterList').val() + ", you have received " + monster.exp + " experience and " + monster.gold + " gold!</p>");
```

To reset the monster's life, you have to add a property to the Monster class to store his amount of life when he's in perfect health :

```
function Monster(name, exp, gold, hp, atk, def, spd) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = name;
    this.exp = exp;
    this.gold = gold;
    this.fullLife = hp;
    this.hp = hp;
    ...
}
```

Then all you have to do is to put back his hp to his fullLife property at the end of the fight :

```
monster.hp = monster.fullLife;
```

Here's the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5cdwu23d/3/

(be carefull though, your playerDam function is not quite fonctionnal, you have some infinite loop there with the `while`, when the monster is to tough for the player and his life never come close to zero)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I do intend to add an if statement that will cause the fight to timeout after a certain amount of rounds

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing p#dam to be a div container. Then just append p tags to it.

So this

```
<p id="dam"></p>
```

becomes this

```
<div id="dam"></div>
```

and this line (54 from your fiddle)

```
$('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsterList').val() + " for " + monster.playerDam() + " damage");
```

becomes this

```
$('#dam').append("<p>You have hit the " + $('#monsterList').val() + " for " + monster.playerDam() + " damage</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by creating all the `<p>` elements in one click of the button, but maybe this will help:

You can create your `<p>` elements in jquery by wrapping the html as a string in the jquery function like so:

`var paragraph = $('<p>Hey</p>');`

One at a time or all at once, you can loop through creating elements in that manner and then use jquery's append to add them to the `#dam` element

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x79x9j85/1/)